# Connecting 2 HDMI monitors with 2 adapters on both side of USB-C port on 2018 MacBook Pro

Tags: display, usb, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

I am thinking of buying 2 of [this](https://www.lazada.com.my/products/ugreen-hdmi-version-usb-c-hub-usb-type-c-31-adapter-dock-with-4k-hdmi-port-3-usb-30-ports-for-lenovo-miix510macbook-pro-2017-2016-dell-xps-15-13-hp-spectreenvy-huawei-mate-10p20-samsung-galaxy-s9-s8-i335445425-s466745687.html) adapter for my Macbook Pro 2018?

By plugging the adapter from both side of the USB-C ports, can i connect it to 2 external HDMI monitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to connect two HDMI monitors using two adapters.

Each of the four USB-C ports (2 on either side) support connecting external display.